# Get the data and total upto that cell in excel

Tags: excel

I have an Excel Sheet called Sheet1. In this sheet I have 12 columns as follows:

```
  |  A   |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |  F  |  G  |  H  |  I  |  J   |  K   |  L
--+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------
1 |  1   |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |  10  |  11  |  12
--+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------
2 | 200  | 200 | 300 | 300 | 400 | 400 | 500 | 500 | 500 |  500 |  500 |  500
```

Now in cell cell `N5`:

```
If I Enter 4 then I should get 300.
If I Enter 12 then I should get 500.
If I Enter 1 then I should get 200.
```

And in cell `N6`, I should get the total upto that cell. Let me explain it with an example:

```
If I enter 4 then I should get 1000, because 200+200+300+300 = 1000
If I enter 12 then I should get 4800 because 200+200+300+300+400+400+500+500+500+500+500+500 = 4800.
If I enter 1 then I should get 200,
If I enter 7 then I should get 2300, because 200+200+300+300+400+400+500 = 2300.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `INDEX(MATCH())` pair to get the single value and combine that in a `SUM` with the first cell in teh range to get the collective total.

[image: SUM(INDEX(MATCH()))]

The formula in N5 is,

`=INDEX($A$2:$L$2,MATCH($M$5,$A$1:$L$1,0))`

The formula in N6 is,

`=SUM(A2:INDEX($A$2:$L$2,MATCH($M$5,$A$1:$L$1,0)))`

Combine these with the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/IFERROR-function-f59bacdc-78bd-4924-91df-a869d0b08cd5) if you require error control when an input value is not found.

Comment: Thanks, that was a great help. I never knew about the index function.